# Can I enable MVC on my ASP web site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a regular ASP.net website and I want to use RESTful API's. Can I use this without creating a new MVC site within Visual Studio?

Comment: Here is how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790679/convert-website-from-webforms-to-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/23/using-asp-net-web-api-with-asp-net-web-forms.aspx) can help you if you want to make use of ASP.NET MVC Web API in a web forms project to implement your RESTful API

If you want to mix in general ASP.NET MVC into an existing Web Forms application you could try something like [this](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet-mvc). There should also be a fair amount of literature on SO and the web on how to mix the two together in one project/solution

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you. I found the second resource to be much more useful